# Program immediately terminates with segfault when using scanf

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, scanf

When I use `gets()` or `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`, the program does execute completely but prints segmentation fault(core dumped) in the end! I don't understand why am I getting segfault in both the cases. Here is the code for converting an infix to postfix exp using stacks.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct stack{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    int *array;
}stack;

stack* createstack(char *);
void push(stack* ,int );
int isempty(stack *);
int pop(stack *st);
int peek(stack *st);
int precedence(char c);

int main(){
char exp[100];
char post[100];
int k=-1;
stack *st;
int i=0,p=0;
printf("enter string expression: ");
//gets(exp); 
//fgets(exp, sizeof(exp), stdin);
scanf("%s",exp);
printf("Infix expression : %s",exp);
st=createstack(exp);

for(i=0;i<strlen(exp);i++){
    if( (exp[i]>='a' && exp[i]<='z') || (exp[i]>='A' && exp[i]<='Z'))
        post[++k]=exp[i];
    else if(exp[i]=='(')
        push(st,exp[i]);
    else if(exp[i]==')'){
        while(!isempty(st) && peek(st)!='(')
            post[++k]=pop(st);
        pop(st);
    }
    else{
        while(precedence(exp[i]) < precedence(peek(st)))
            post[++k]=pop(st);
        push(st,exp[i]);
    }
}
while(!isempty(st))
    post[++k]=pop(st);

//post[++k]='\0';
printf("Postfix expression :\n%s\n",post);
return 0;

}

stack* createstack(char *exp){
stack* st;
st->top=-1;
st->capacity=strlen(exp);
st->array=(int*)malloc(st->capacity * sizeof(int));
printf("Stack created successfully\n");
return st;
}

void push(stack* st,int val){
st->array[++st->top]=val;
}

int isempty(stack *st){
return st->top==-1;
}

int pop(stack *st){
return st->array[st->top--];
}

int peek(stack *st){
return st->array[st->top];
}

int precedence(char c){
switch(c){
    case '(':
        return 0;
        break;
    case '+':
        return 1;
        break;
    case '-':
        return 1;
        break;
    case '*':
        return 2;
        break;
    case '/':
        return 2;
        break;

    case '^':
        return 3;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: minor note: please try to give a minimum code example. in your case, you could probably reduce it to 5 to 10 lines. this saves time of people who read your answer, and makes the question more general, which means it can help more people with similar problems. it will also maybe help you to find the error yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code,

```
stack* st;
st->top=-1;
```

you're using `st` uninitialized which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory to `st` before using it.

Try something like

```
stack* st = malloc(sizeof*st);  //also, check for malloc success
```

That said,

1. Please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.
2. The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.